# Which are the differences of NGSI-LD and JSON-LD?

Tags: fiware

In Fiware tutorials I read that NGSI-LD is not 100% JSON-LD. Can you explain me which are the differences?

Answer (score 8):

[JSON-LD](https://json-ld.org/) is an extension to JavaScript Object notation which enables linked data concepts to be expressed in JSON and provide a format which is both human and computer readable. This is JSON-LD:

##### JSON-LD

```json
{
  "@context": "https://json-ld.org/contexts/person.jsonld",
  "@id": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/John_Lennon",
  "name": "John Lennon",
  "born": "1940-10-09",
  "spouse": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cynthia_Lennon"
}
```

NGSI-LD is an API which uses multiple payload formats, but here is the **John Lennon** entity expressed using "normalized" NGSI-LD - one of several formats that all NGSI context-brokers must support (they also cover plain key-values JSON and [GeoJSON](https://geojson.org/) for example - see below).

##### "normalized" NGSI-LD

###### GET `../ngsi-ld/v1/entities/John_Lennon` Content-Type: `application/ld+json`

```json
{
   "@context":  [
     "https://json-ld.org/contexts/person.jsonld",
     "https://uri.etsi.org/ngsi-ld/v1/ngsi-ld-core-context.jsonld"
  ],
   "id": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/John_Lennon",
   "type": "Person",
   "name": {"type": "Property", "value": "John Lennon"},
   "born": {"type": "Property", "value": "1940-10-09"},
   "spouse": {
      "type": "Relationship", "object": 
      "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cynthia_Lennon"
   }
}
```

Every NSGI-LD payload is a valid JSON-LD document. However this "normalized" NGSI-LD format has additional rules and restrictions (e.g. all attributes must have a `type` of `Property` or `Relationship`) therefore not all JSON-LD snippets are valid "normalized" NGSI-LD.

Much like JSON-LD being *JSON plus linked data concepts*, NGSI-LD is *NGSI-v2 plus linked data concepts*.

The [NGSI-LD specification](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gs/CIM/001_099/009/01.04.01_60/gs_cim009v010401p.pdf) describes how to make requests to a context broker and the expected format of the responses. There are 27 well-defined operations within NGSI. Additionally NGSI-LD defines strict definitions of terms such as **Subscription** and **Registration** and **Property** and **Relationship**, how timestamps should only be held in an `observedAt`, geographical position must be found in a `location` attribute as a GeoJSON `Point` and so on.

[image: NGSI-LD Entities, Properties and Relationship]

JSON-LD is a data representation only, it makes no assumptions about how the payload is to be accessed or how the payload is to be structured beyond having attributes in JSON format and an `@context` attribute.

Context-Broker to Context-Broker operations in "normalized" NGSI-LD can make the assumption that the core context `https://uri.etsi.org/ngsi-ld/v1/ngsi-ld-core-context.jsonld` is assumed to be part of the request and is processed **last** and therefore always overrides other `@context` elements. the `@context` element can also be represented using a [Link Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Link)

JSON-LD representations must always contain an `@context` attribute (after all that is what makes them `application/ld+json` rather than just plain `application/json`) and the [`@context`](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#the-context) is processed according the order of the array of elements found.

Since NGSI-LD is defined as an API, responses to NGSI-LD requests may also be returned in JSON `application/json` and GeoJSON `application/geo+json` format or as "normalized" or as key-value pairs with or without the `@context` and `Properties` annotations. For example, the key-values format will return the **John_Lennon** entity as follows:

##### "key-values" NGSI-LD

###### GET `../ngsi-ld/v1/entities/John_Lennon?options=keyValues` Content-Type: `application/ld+json`

```json
{
  "@context": "https://json-ld.org/contexts/person.jsonld",
  "name": "John Lennon",
  "born": "1940-10-09",
  "spouse": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cynthia_Lennon"
}
```

which is the same as the original JSON-LD example. And it's also possible to return as plain JSON or [GeoJSON](https://geojson.org/) by amending the content-type.

###### GET `../ngsi-ld/v1/entities/John_Lennon?options=keyValues` Content-Type: `application/json`

```json
{
  "name": "John Lennon",
  "born": "1940-10-09",
  "spouse": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cynthia_Lennon"
}
```

###### GET `../ngsi-ld/v1/entities/John_Lennon?options=keyValues` Content-Type: `application/geo+json`

```json
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-73.975, 40.775556]
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "John Lennon",
    "born": "1940-10-09",
    "spouse": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cynthia_Lennon"
  }
}
```

"normalized" is typically used for broker-to-broker data exchange. "keyValues" is more likely to be  used by an application developer. Indeed when you get the data back as just JSON all the attributes have been washed using a [expansion](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#expanded-document-form)/[compaction](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#compacted-document-form) operation which means that you can get data from multiple sources using different attribute names to return using a single common short name for agreed [IRIs](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#iris) -  this is the goal of an interoperability exchange API for data.

So in summary the "normalized" NGSI-LD format is an extended subset of JSON-LD. The [NGSI-LD API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NGSI-LD) itself is a more flexible API which outputs various JSON and JSON-LD formats and is used for data exchange.

If you need more information, there is also a more extensive review of NGSI-LD data formats (including a new "concise" data format) in a recent [Video Presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-XPGyM7K_kU&t=242s) from the FIWARE Foundation.